# Anybody know where I can get some Stanley spatulas?

Tags: baking, equipment

[image: stanley spatula]

Back when Stanley had home parties, the demonstrator would hand these out as a hostess prize or thank you. It’s my absolute favorite spatula and I cannot seem to find one anywhere! It’s a soft, pliable, probably nylon spatula.

Comment: That looks very similar to the [Kenwood flexible plastic spatula](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Kenwood-VDTAZ012A-plastic-cooking-spatula/dp/B0013HH8XG)  of which I have two (you can find them cheaper I'm sure)

Answer (score 1):

Having looked online and using the excellent Google image matching facility, this appears to be an antique item, circa 1950. The closest match I could find was on an auctioneers valuation site, which suggests not only are they rare, but valuable as well [1].

I can't recommend these spatulas enough [2], they are not cheap, but they are a joy to use.

[1] https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/maid-honor-spatula-slotted-spoon-1854740164

[2] https://www.dontwasteyourmoney.com/products/di-oro-heat-resistant-nonstick-silicone-rubber-spatula-3-piece/